# Connection R to Cassandra using RCassandra

Tags: r, cassandra

I have an instance of Cassandra running on my localhost. For this example I have used the default configuration provided in conf\cassandra.yaml

I tried to connect R to Cassandra using the RCassandra package.

Basically, i have just installed the RCassandra package in R and tried to connect.

```
library("RCassandra")
RC.connect('localhost','9160')
RC.connect('127.0.0.1','9160')
```

None of those are working. Here is the error I get:

```
Error in RC.connect("localhost", port = "9160") : 
  cannot connect to locahost:9160
```

Using Cassandra-cli with the same parameters work. Can you please help on that.

Thank you

Comment: I'm not familiar with Cassandra, but it sounds like your configuration is either set up on a different port or not set up with that interface.  What happens when you telnet to localhost port 9160?

Comment: It is `localhost` not `locahost` check where does it come from :) Error in RC.connect("**locahost**"

Comment: Sorry for the typo, edited. Abi, how would you try that in telnet?

Answer (score 2):

Set `start_rpc: true` in cassandra.yaml file.

Comment: Or `nodetool enablethrift`

Answer (score 1):

Could not fix it but found a way to make it work: initiate a jdbc connection and then launch RCassandra

```
  #Load RJDBC

library(RJDBC)

#Load in the Cassandra-JDBC diver
cassdrv <- JDBC("org.apache.cassandra.cql.jdbc.CassandraDriver",
        list.files("C://Users//aab_ITSolutions//apache-cassandra-1.0.10//lib",pattern="jar$",full.names=T))

#Connect to Cassandra node and Keyspace
casscon <- dbConnect(cassdrv, "jdbc:cassandra://localhost:9160/DEMO")

#Query timeseries data
res <- dbGetQuery(casscon, "select * from StockHist limit 10")

library("RCassandra")

connx = RC.connect('localhost',9160)
```